# Yahoo OAuth: Not Found on Accelerator

Tags: android, oauth, titanium-mobile, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I have been trying to get contacts via Yahoo OAUTH for over 4 hours now.. finally in the last stage.Have been following [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html#contacts_resources-scopes) very closely and am successfully getting the request token too.But when i fetch the following url:

> https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/(guid)/contacts

along with the parameters mentioned [here.](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html)

I am simply getting an HTTP Error

> Not Found on Accelerator

This is what i am trying to get now..

```
https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/(some guid)/contacts?format=json&realm=yahooapis.com&oauth_consumer_key=(some key)&oauth_nonce=p0p@wA$h3rE&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1363691527&oauth_token=(access token here)&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=(some sign)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url was wrong,It should be as the follows as given in the yahoo api docs

> <strike>https</strike> **http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/(guid)/contacts**

Answer (score 0):

```
// your url .........
 var url = "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/"+guid+"/contacts?format=json";
```

// you need to make it json request all your data

```
 var data = JSON.stringify({
    realm="yahooapis.com",
  oauth_consumer_key="dj0yJmk9nM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1lMg--",
  oauth_nonce="24829.2331",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="1219450170",
  oauth_token="A%3DuqkiebGpiTJl7ThQxU.jDXXaETYyfEy3xAKPyoavokwOOcZcz8Xs_l1Nvnl._
    KmCEVCeLkxxT1Y6BgRqf5f98sQWHklBM_anetveR7okK_M_5XEmQ1_1reo3UgKQULT_dQT8Gao3.
    Rrgz5rJxgmnYrhdWWdfgTdMQVzpbJT2aGkz59NTK1O8yXVE1EvZUCqju7WiFYu.WHNEw.9TWq3g--",
  oauth_version="1.0",
  oauth_signature="O2AQipLITO0aYHKZc9266RzC94%3D"


  });




 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {

     },
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug(e.error);
         alert('error');
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("GET", url);
 client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
 client.send(data);
```

Comment: where did you get this from?

Comment: this is wrong code sundar.the var `data` is not even correct JSON.It will throw error on compile

Comment: by da ways you commented on prev question.. that issue got over now this one.

Comment: see dont try code as it is it an example change the some of the feilds like auth_token to variables..i mean give your variables like var authtoken ="ur token" and give this in data oauth_token=authtoken and try .. it wont

Comment: or remove JSON strinfy .. just pass data as dict in send .... try both ..surely it you will get.. i have tried in many request like this..it worked .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26460/discussion-between-sundar-nataraj-and-nezam)